# I would like to be able to take a screen shot every 6 hours and email it

Tags: email

This might sound like a random idea though I need it to monitor something on it.

I run software I need to make sure it is continually running. If I can just get it to screen shot every 6 hours and email it to my phone it would be perfect.

I am sure this would be possible with enough ingenuity.

I am not a coder and I appreciate any help. Cheers.

Comment: Besides the bandwidth required to send screenshots, and the available space on your phone, this may not be the best way to do what you want. If your software has a specific process name, it would be easier/faster to `ps auxc | grep -i process_name` and pipe that into a mail message. Or, better yet, create a .service file that would restart the software automatically if it quits/aborts/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function in my `~/.bashrc` to create a screenshot:

```
screenshot () 
{ 
    import -window root ~/var/screenshot/$(tshhmmss)_screendump.png
}
```

It uses one of my personal aliases, `tshhmmss` (also in ~/.bashrc`):

```
alias tshhmmss="date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S"
```

Then, write a simple `bash` script to set `DISPLAY`, generate the screenshot, and mail it. Add this to your `crontab`, set to run every 6 hours.

You have to set `DISPLAY`, because `import` needs to find it, and `cron` jobs are not run under the GUI context. In a GUI terminal window, `echo $DISPLAY` will show the value you need.